# How to calculate size of structure with bit field?

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h> 
struct test { 
unsigned int x; 
long int y : 33; 
unsigned int z; 
};  
int main() 
{ 
struct test t; 
printf("%d", sizeof(t)); 
return 0;
```

}

I am getting the output as 24. How does it equate to that?

Comment: padding.  ......

Comment: And you compare pointers to **int** when they are not in a same array. The result is simply undefined. If you want to evaluate sizes inside a struct, only use pointers to **char**

Comment: OT: Indent yout code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your implementation accepts `long int y : 33;` a long int hase more than 32 bits on your system, so I shall assume 64.

If plain `int` are also 64 bits, the result of 24 is normal.

If they are only 32 bits, you have encountered *padding* and *alignment*. For performance reasons, 64 bits types on 64 bits systems are aligned on a 64 bits boundary. So you have:

- 4 bytes for the first int
- 4 padding bytes to have a 8 bytes boundary
- 8 bytes for the container of the bit field
- 4 bytes for the second int
- 4 padding bytes to allow proper alignment of arrays

Total: 24 bytes

Comment: "8 bytes for the container of the bit field" --> More like "33 bits for the bit field and 31 padding bits".   Those 31 bts could have accommodated another bit field.  Had a  `char` followed `long int y : 33;`, I would have expected less padding  bits and the same overall size for OP.  Other than that a good answer.